# What assemblies do I need to start using Castle Windsor in my application?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I've got a pretty basic question about how to start using Castle Windsor.  I've read up on IOC/DI and would like to try Castle Windsor in an existing solution.  I typically like to put any external assemblies in a Lib folder within the solution's folder tree so that the references are relative (I believe this is best practice).

Which assemblies from  the Castle\Bin... folder do I need to copy to my Lib folder?  And do I need to add an explicit reference to each assembly or only some of them?

There are 30 assemblies in the C:\dev\oss\Castle\Bin\net-2.0 folder and 18 assemblies in the C:\dev\oss\Castle\Bin\Dependencies folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reckon this should be enough to get you started.

- Castle.Core
- Castle.MicroKernel
- Castle.Windsor

and if you want to use log4net for logging then....

- log4net
- Castle.Facilities.Logging
- Castle.Services.Logging.Log4netIntegration

Answer (score 2):

Only Castle.Core, Castle.MicroKernel and Castle.Windsor are required to be able to use Windsor.